# Cordova app deployment on device

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm using Eclipse to run my android mobile app. The problem is that when modify code the change not appear in the deployed app on device. Remain ever the same app on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are changing code in `yourProject->www` folder, then you need to build it first with command prompt /cli

OR you need to directly change the files in `yourProject->platforms->...->www` before running from Eclipse

Comment: I'm sorry which prompt?

Comment: @StefanoMaglione In windows it's command prompt, in linux/mac it's terminal. CLI - command line interface